How can I catch an error in node.js using wrapper function?
I am using an AsyncHandler wrapper function to catch my errors in my controller and service layer.
I am using next() parameter to raise an error, and then catch it in my global error handler.
My global error handler is executing but my controller is also returning, even though it should haven't return anything after error is thrown.
My Controller layer:
const categoryCtrl = {
  create: asyncHandler( async (req, res, next) => {

    const data = await CategoryService.createCategory("", 4, next)

   return  successResponse({res, data:data, msg:"Category created Successfully"})

  }),
  getAll: async (req, res, next) => {},
  getById: async (req, res, next) => {},
  delete: async (req, res, next) => {},
  update: async (req, res, next) => {},
};

My service layer:
const categoryService = {
  createCategory: async (data, x, next) => {
  
      if (data === "") {
        console.log("condition");
        const err = new CustomError(404, "Wrong input");
        return next(err);
      } else {
        return data;
      }

  },
};

My asyncHandler :
const asyncHandler = (func) => {
  return  (req, res, next) => {
    try {
       func(req, res, next)

    } catch (error) {
      next(error)

    }


  };
};

My successReponse:
module.exports  = ({res, msg, data}) => {

    return res.status(200).json({msg:msg, data: data})

}

I have tried to use throw, but I am trying to avoid try-catch block in my controller layer and service layer and raise error only throw using next() parameter.

Does this answer your question? Is there a way to wrap an await/async try/catch block to every function?

Your createCategory function should not have a next parameter at all. Just throw your error.


I have tried to use throw, but I am trying to avoid try-catch block in my controller layer and service layer and raise error only throw using next() parameter.

That would have been the correct approach. If you want to use exceptions, you actually have to use them! Notice that you don't actually need a try/catch in your controller, that's precisely what the asyncHandler is doing for you. Notice that if you weren't using exceptions, you would have to return an error code (e.g. null instead of a data object) from the service, and explicitly check that in your controller so that you return successResponse conditionally. You don't want that - only exceptions can achieve the goal of not requiring extra syntax in intermediate layers between the service and asyncHandler.
// Controller:
const categoryCtrl = {
  create: asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
    const data = await CategoryService.createCategory("", 4, next)
    return successResponse({res, data, msg: "Category created Successfully"});
  }),
  getAll: asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {}),
  getById: asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {}),
  delete: asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {}),
  update: asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {}),
};

// Service layer:
const categoryService = {
  async createCategory(data, x) {
    if (data === "") {
      console.log("condition");
      throw new CustomError(404, "Wrong input");
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  },
};

Using
const asyncHandler = (func) => (req, res, next) => {
  func(req, res, next).catch(next);
};
// or
const asyncHandler = (func) => async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await func(req, res)
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};


It looks like the asyncHandler is not correctly handling the asynchronous nature of the operations inside it. Specifically, it does not await the completion of the func it wraps.
You can modify your asyncHandler to properly handle asynchronous functions like this

const asyncHandler = (func) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    func(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
};


This asyncHandler now explicitly handles the promise returned by the func.

I've had done this as well, my main concern is with my service and controller layer, when i throw a n Error in my service layer, it works fine and my global error gets executed, but after that, my controller layer also gets executed and it executes "successResponse" function in controller layer

Thank you for the clarification. The problem you're facing usually arises because the control flow isn't properly halted after the error is handled in the asynchronous function. If you're calling next(err) in the service layer and still seeing the successResponse function being executed afterward, it suggests that the asynchronous nature of the function isn't fully being accounted for, or the return of control isn't properly managed. Watch the new answer i'm gonna post now.

Each of the other answers here had a small piece of the puzzle, so I'm going to try to put the whole thing together here.
The main problem is in your controller. The create method calls the createCategory method of the service, which correctly calls the next function when it sees the input it doesn't want to process. The issue is that, because no error is thrown, the create method in the controller never gets any indication that it shouldn't continue on with its tasks once createCategory finishes. That's why you're seeing output both for your next error handler and for sendSuccessResponse.
Here's what worked for me to get it only firing off the next function:
First, I threw an error from createCategory:
const categoryService = {
  createCategory: async (data, x, next) => {
    if (data === "") {
      throw new CustomError(404, "Wrong input");
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  },
};

Next, I added a try/catch block to the controller - I'm curious to know why you were looking to avoid this pattern, as it's the one I'm most familiar with. In my experience it's quite common to call an error handler in the catch block at the controller level.
const categoryCtrl = {
  create: asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const data = await categoryService.createCategory("", 4, next);
      return sendSuccessResponse({
        res,
        data,
        msg: "Category created Successfully",
      });
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  }),
};

This successfully resulted in only seeing the "Wrong input" message log to the console. (My next function was just a log: (err) => console.log(err.message)).
I'm pretty sure that the asyncHandler layer here is causing you more problems than it's solving. You can remove that function entirely and update your controller to look like this:
const categoryCtrl = {
  create: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const data = await categoryService.createCategory("", 4, next);
      return sendSuccessResponse({
        res,
        data: data,
        msg: "Category created Successfully",
      });
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  },
};


Update your controller by this
const categoryCtrl = {
  create: asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const data = await CategoryService.createCategory("", 4, next);
    if (data instanceof Error) {
      return;  
    }
    return successResponse({ res, data: data, msg: "Category created Successfully" });
  }),
  // your other methods will reside here
};

Update your service layer by this
const categoryService = {
  createCategory: async (data, x, next) => {
    if (data === "") {
      console.log("condition");
      const err = new CustomError(404, "Wrong input");
      next(err);
      return err;  
    } else {
      return data;  
    }
  },
  // your other methods reside here.
}; ``


You can [edit] your answer to use code formatting instead of blockquotes
